# DNS: retrieving host IP address using resolv.h

Tags: c, dns, bind, resolv

I'm trying to understand DNS queries using the `resolv.h` library in BIND.
I'm struggling trying to parse an IP address from RRs returned by  `ns_parserr()`.
I can successfully parse authoritative NS using the code provided by https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/dns/ch15_02.htm , but I can't seem to be able to obtain the `A` type records and **print them**.
Mainly because I don't know how IP addresses are codified inside the `ns_rr` structure. Looking at the implementation, RDATA are of `const u_char *` type.
How to get the IP out of this record?

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
     union {
        HEADER hdr;              
        u_char buf[NS_PACKETSZ]; 
    } response;                  
    int responseLen;             
    res_init();
    ns_msg handle;
    responseLen =res_query(argv[1],ns_c_in,ns_t_a,(u_char *)&response,sizeof(response));
    if (responseLen<0)
        exit(-1);
    if (ns_initparse(response.buf, responseLen, &handle)<0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR PARSING RESPONSE....");
        perror("damn");
        exit(-1);

    }
    ns_rr rr;
    int rrnum;
    ns_sect section=ns_s_an;
    for (rrnum=0;rrnum<(ns_msg_count(handle,section));rrnum++)
    {
        if (ns_parserr(&handle,ns_s_an,rrnum,&rr)<0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR PARSING RRs");
            exit(-1);
        }   

        if (ns_rr_type(rr)==ns_t_a)
        {
            [WHAT TO DO HERE?]
        }
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

I usually try to fix these things by myself, but there are not many information about the `resolv.h` library on the internet, except for the cited source.
Thank you all for you support, I appreciate that.

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to learn about the DNS, but you might have a look at the getdns API as it is newer and better for all stuff related to DNSSEC.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thank you. I'll give a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse the resource record data in `ns_rr` yourself; the format is described in rfc1035 (see [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035), the A rdata format is in section 3.4.1)

In your `[WHAT TO DO HERE?]`, you could for example parse the A rdata and print the IP like this:

```
struct in_addr in;
memcpy(&in.s_addr, ns_rr_rdata(rr), sizeof(in.s_addr));
fprintf(stderr, "%s IN A %s\n", ns_rr_name(rr), inet_ntoa(in));
```

If you want to support other resource record types you will have to familiarize yourself with their specific format.

Comment: Thank you for the RFC. I had actually already tried using `struct in_addr`, but didn't use `memcpy`. This solved my problem! Thank you!